Test a string variable if it fit's into a predefined pattern
I need to test string variables to fit into a predefined pattern.
In my case, there are two different pattern which I need to test.
KNX Physical Address

KNX addresses are valid in this format XX.XX.XXX
The complete value range is from 01.00.000 til 15.15.255

Cable Types

The predefined cable Types have the format Typ-X or in case there are two types available Typ-X / Typ-Y. More than two cable types are forbidden.
The complete value range is Typ-1 til Typ-6 OR Typ-1 / Typ-1 til Typ-6 / Typ-6

Can anyone give me a proposal how test this in an efficient way? Of course I could write a massive routine with several \ifthenelse statements but I hope that there is any kind of package or maybe an expl3 implementation to test against such patterns.
Of course I could also do this outside of LaTeX, but it would be great to see a LaTeX solution for this. I often have to work with external input data which I need to test within LaTeX.

Are you aware that expl3 has regular expressions?   Chapter 8 in texdoc interface3.

can you provide an MWE? Or an MNWE? What @Teepeemm said or Lua, if luaTeX is an option.

@Teepeemm I don't have this deep knowledge about texdoc interface3 but thanks for the hint, I will train myself with the help of the solution from matexmatics!

@cfr Normally I add MWE's, but in this case I had no clue how to establish something like this.

Below, the commands \testKNX and \testcable are defined. They test for a regular expression as suggested by @Teepeemm. Edit: the code is optimized with the suggestions from @cfr in the comments.
Edit 2: Set a KNX address also invalid if this address is used twice, as asked in the comments. Moreover, the combination of \regex_new:N and \regex_set:Nn is replaced by \regex_const:Nn.
\documentclass[border=6pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__PascalS_invalid: { invalid~input }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__PascalS_valid: { valid~input }

\regex_const:Nn \c__PascalS_KNX_regex { ^\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{3}$ }%$ an extra dollar to form a pair with the previous one for syntax highlighting

\seq_new:N \g__PascalS_KNX_seq

\NewDocumentCommand \testKNX { m }
  {
    #1 \c_colon_str {} ~
    \regex_match:NnTF \c__PascalS_KNX_regex {#1}
      {
        \int_compare:nTF { 0 < \str_range:nnn {#1} { 1 } { 2 } < 16 }
          {
            \int_compare:nTF { -1 < \str_range:nnn {#1} { 4 } { 5 } < 16 }
              {
                \int_compare:nTF { -1 < \str_range:nnn {#1} { 7 } { 9 } < 256 }
                  {
                    \seq_if_in:NnTF \g__PascalS_KNX_seq {#1}
                      { \__PascalS_invalid: }
                      {
                        \seq_gput_right:Nn \g__PascalS_KNX_seq {#1}
                        \__PascalS_valid:
                      }
                  }
                  { \__PascalS_invalid: }
              }
              { \__PascalS_invalid: }
          }
          { \__PascalS_invalid: }
      }
      { \__PascalS_invalid: }
  }

\regex_const:Nn \c__PascalS_cable_A_regex { ^Typ\-[1-6]$ }%$
\regex_const:Nn \c__PascalS_cable_B_regex { ^Typ\-[1-6]\ /\ Typ\-[1-6]$ }%$

\NewDocumentCommand \testcable { m }
  {
    #1 \c_colon_str {} ~
    \regex_match:NnTF \c__PascalS_cable_A_regex {#1}
      { \__PascalS_valid: }
      {
        \regex_match:NnTF \c__PascalS_cable_B_regex {#1}
          { \__PascalS_valid: }
          { \__PascalS_invalid: }
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\testKNX{00.00.000}\\
\testKNX{01.00.000}\\
\testKNX{16.15.000}\\
\testKNX{15.15.256}\\
\testKNX{01.00.000}\\
\testcable{Typ-1}\\
\testcable{Typ-2/Typ-3}\\
\testcable{Typ-4 / Typ-5}
\end{document}



Absolute amazing! Thank you so much!

@cfr Thank you for the suggestions to improve the code. The answer has been updated.

good job.  >^.^<

@matexmatics Can you just tell me, why \edef\testPattern{11.10.250} \testKNX{\testPattern}is invalid, whereas \testKNX{11.10.250}is valid? Do I have to pay attention regarding expansion here?

@Pascal This is indeed related to expansion. Here are some options: \testKNX{11.10.250}\\ \def\testPattern{11.10.250} \ExplSyntaxOn \exp_args:NV \testKNX \testPattern \\ \ExplSyntaxOff \expandafter\testKNX\expanded{{\testPattern}}. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/603954.

Great this works for me! Thank you!

@matexmatics sorry for asking again, but is there also a simple approach to set a KNX address also invalid, if this is address is used twice? So first check, if the pattern fit's and then test if this address is already used. I thought about using a dynamical array, and add every tested KNX address. But probably there is a better solution in expl3.

@Pascal See the updated answer. Moreover, the combination of \regex_new:N and \regex_set:Nn is replaced by \regex_const:Nn.

You can use \A and \Z for matching start and end instead of ^ and $.

@matexmatics That's it! Thanks!

@matexmatics When I set \cs_new_protected:Npn \__PascalS_valid: {valid} the returned string is valid of course. But When I try to test this string within an \ifthenelse statement, it never success. So is there an easy answer, why \ifthenelse{\equal{\testKNX{01.00.000}}{valid}}{YES}{NO} is never returning YES completely independent of the address I test? If it is more complex I would create a new question :)

I just created a new question as I think this is off topic to the root question.

@Pascal Use for example `\cs_new_protected:Npn __PascalS_invalid: { \def \result { invalid } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn __PascalS_valid: { \def \result { valid } }and comment the lines#1 \c_colon_str {} ~. Then this test can be performed with \testKNX{01.00.000}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\result}{valid}}{YES}{NO}`.

Use regexes.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\checkKNX}{m}
 {
  \pascal_checkknx:e {#1}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \pascal_checkknx:n
 {% check for two digits, period, two digits, period, three digits
  \regex_match:nnTF { \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{3} } {#1}
   {% success, check for the range
    \__pascal_checkknx_range:n {#1}
   }
   {% not matching
    #1~is~an~invalid~KNX~address
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \pascal_checkknx:n { e }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__pascal_checkknx_range:n
 {
  \__pascal_checkknx:nw {#1} #1 \q_stop
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__pascal_checkknx:nw #1 #2 . #3 . #4 \q_stop
 {
  \bool_if:nTF
   {
    \int_compare_p:n { 0 <= #2 <= 15 }
    &&
    \int_compare_p:n { 0 <= #3 <= 15 }
    &&
    \int_compare_p:n { 0 <= #4 <= 255 }
   }
   { #1~is~a~valid~KNX~address }
   { #1~is~an~invalid~KNX~address }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\checkcable}{m}
 {
  \pascal_checkcable:e {#1}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \pascal_checkcable:n
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { Typ-[123456] } {#1}
   {
    #1~is~a~valid~cable~type
   }
   {
    \pascal_checkcable_double:n {#1}
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \pascal_checkcable:n { e }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \pascal_checkcable_double:n
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { Typ-[123456] \s* / \s* Typ-[123456] } {#1}
   {
    #1~is~a~valid~cable~type
   }
   {
    #1~is~an~invalid~cable~type
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\myKNX}{02.14.201}
\newcommand{\mycableA}{Typ-3}
\newcommand{\mycableB}{Typ-3/Typ-1}

\begin{document}

\checkKNX{0.1}

\checkKNX{\myKNX}

\checkKNX{00.00.000}

\checkKNX{01.00.000}

\checkKNX{16.15.000}

\checkKNX{15.15.256}

\checkKNX{01.00.00}

\checkcable{Typ-1}

\checkcable{Typ-0}

\checkcable{\mycableA}

\checkcable{\mycableB}

\checkcable{Typ-2/Typ-3}

\checkcable{Typ-2/Typ-7}

\checkcable{Typ-4 / Typ-5}

\end{document}

If you want to enforce spaces around the slash in cable types, then use
Typ-[123456] \s / \s Typ-[123456]

for the “double cable” check.

Since a match in \checkKNX guarantees that the input is “two digits, period, two digits, period, three digits”, we can use a simpler method for splitting the argument at periods. Also we can do multiple boolean checks in a single swoop with \bool_if:nTF, that accepts any boolean expression as its first argument.
You can also see that, using e-expansion, the argument to the check functions can be a macro containing an address or a cable type.

Thanks for your alternative solution!

@egreg A small detail: 00.00.000 is now valid but should be invalid according to the range in the question so 0 <= #2 <= 15 should be replaced by 1 <= #2 <= 15. The regexes are missing a start and end of the subject token list: for example \checkKNX{0+01.00.000} and \checkcable{aTyp-1} are now valid but should be invalid.
